# I want to read data out by linked server in SSMS

Tags: ssms, linked-server

> Msg 7356, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "" supplied inconsistent metadata for a column. The column "" (compile-time ordinal 11) of object "" was reported to have a "DBCOLUMNFLAGS_ISLONG" of 128 at compile time and 0 at run time.

And O also got these message when I just want read out a single column and not that one which has some problem.

I try to use `SELECT * from ....` reading form and
`SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([], '')` also.

Comment: Show us your *actual* query here.

Comment: Also SSMS is just an IDE like application, it's not the data engine you are using. SSMS is very likely completely unrelated to the problem here. Instead tag the (R)DBMS product(s) you are using here.

Comment: Please use the [edit] feature, @Mart .